# Is there a way to get the current post URL in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I need the post URL for some Share buttons. Is there a way to retrieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can retrieve the post URL via a [layout data tag](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47270): `data:post.url`

If you just want to insert its value as text in your template, use it as tag: `<data:post.url>`

If you want to use a tag value for a html attribute, precede the html attribute with the prefix expr, for example:

```
<body expr:class='data:blog.mobileClass'>
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Used below script in my blog (www.it.itmrk.com), which is working for me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var postUrl = '<data:post.url/>';
     document.write("<div class="fb-like" data-href='" + postUrl + "' data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>");
</script>
```

Its give link of each post accordingly. It might help full for you also.

Answer (score 0):

You must create an expression, then name the metadata, and in quotation marks the value that you will have. In this way, blogger knows what convets the expression to metadata of the "div"

**example code:**

```
<div class="fb-like"  expr:data-href='data:post.url' data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```